# primefaces clearFilters function clears filters but does not start filter events

Tags: datatable, primefaces, lazy-loading

I am using lazy loading in a `<p:dataTable>` and try to clear filters with Widget: `PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.clearFilters()`
Although this function clears all the filters, filter events does not start. So the `Map<String, String>` filters values remain same and datatable does not get updated.

```
public List<LazyModelInterface> load(int startingAt, 
       int maxPerPage, 
       String sortField, 
       SortOrder sortOrder, 
       Map<String, 
       String> filters)
```

Comment: Please provide more information: Which PF version, scope of Bean, snippet from site.xhtml. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How about using some `f:ajax` (`h:commandButton` for example) with listener pointing to a method that will execute the following code

```
public void resetFilters(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
            .findComponent("myFormId:myTableId");
    if (dataTable != null) {
        dataTable.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i want the remaining parts to stay same. There is a tag in Datatable as filterEvent with default value "keyup". I believe because of that clearFilters() does not start filterEvents. Changing filterEvent didn't work so far.